# A closed function and a $T_2$ space

Tags: general-topology

The next exercise is so difficult. I have some idea, but, I can't conclude.

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a $T_2$ space with the next propertie: if $\sigma$ is a $T_2$ topology for $X$ and $\sigma\subset\tau$, then, $\sigma=\tau$.
>
> Let $Y$ be a $T_2$ space. Prove that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an embedding, then $f$ is a closed function.
>
> Hint: Suposse that $f[X]$ is not closed in $Y$. Take $b\in\text{cl}_Y(f[X])\setminus f[X]$ (here, $\text{cl}_Y$ is the closure in the $Y$ space) and consider the subspace $Z=f[X]\cup\{b\}$. Take a fixed point $a\in X$. What happened with the next family? ($\tau_z$ is the topology on $Z$).
>
> $$\sigma=\left\{u\in\tau \  | \ \ (a\in U \Rightarrow f[U]\cup\{b\}\in\tau_z) \right\}$$

My attempt

First, we claim that $\sigma$ is a topology for $X$.

$1)$ Clearly, $\emptyset,X\in\sigma$

$2)$ If we take $A,B\in\sigma$, there are two cases:

- If $a\not\in A\cap B$, then, clearly $A\cap B\in\sigma$
- If $a\in A\cap B$, then, $a\in A $ and $a\in B$, and since $A,B\in\sigma$, then, $f[A]\cup\{b\}\in \tau_z$ and $f[B]\cup\{b\}\in\tau$, then, $\left(f[A]\cup\{b\}\right)\bigcap\left(f[B]\cup\{b\}\right)=f[A\cap B]\cup\{b\}\in\tau_z$

$3)$ Take $\left\{V_i:i\in I\right\}\subseteq\sigma$. We want to prove that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i\in\sigma$

- If $a\notin\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$, then, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i\in\sigma$
- If $a\in \displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i$, because $V_i\in\sigma$ for all $i\in I$, then, $f[V_i]\cup\{b\}\in\tau_z$. Finally, $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}f[V_i]\cup\{b\}=f\left[\displaystyle\bigcup_{i\in I}V_i\right]\cup\{b\}\in\tau_z$

Then, I want to prove that $X$ equipped with $\sigma$ is $T_2$.

Take $x,y\in X$, with $x\neq y$.
$f[X]\cup\{b\}$ is $T_2$, then, there exist $U$ and $V$ open and disjoint sets in $\tau_z$ such that $f(x)\in U$ and $f(y)\in V$. In this way, because $f$ is an embedding, $f^{-1}[U]$ and $f^{-1}[V]$ are disjoint open sets in $\sigma$ and $x\in f^{-1}[U]$ and $y\in f^{-1}[V]$. Thus, $\sigma$ is $T_2$ and by hypothesis, $\sigma=\tau$ since $\sigma\subset\tau$ clearly.

But, from here, how can I obtain a contradiction? I don't know how to conclude.

I really appreciate any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\sigma \subset \tau$ and is Hausdorff as you showed.
Also as $(Z, \tau_Z)$ is Hausdorff, so $f(a)$ and $b$ have disjoint neighbourhoods $U_a$ and $U_b$ in $\tau_Z$, and as $U_b \cap f[X] \neq \emptyset$, $f^{-1}[U_a]$ and $f^{-1}[U_b \cap f[X]]$ are disjoint and non-empty. This shows that $f^{-1}[U_a] \in \tau\setminus \sigma$. For if $U_a \in \sigma$ then $O = f[U_a] \cup \{b\}$ would be open in $Z$, but then $\{b\}$ would be isolated in $Z$ as witnessed by $U_b$: $U_b \cap O = \{b\}$. This cannot be as $b \in \overline{f[X]}\setminus f[X]$

So $\sigma$ is a proper subset of $\tau$
and this gives us the contradiction. So $f[X]$ is closed in $Y$, and an embedding with a closed image is clearly a closed map.

The result is known as "a minimally Hausdorff space is $H$-closed"; more info can be found in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/135744/4280).